# Github Action Branch "feature" is not allowed to deploy to dev due to environment protection rules

Tags: github, github-actions

I have setup one Github Action workflow. In which I want to trigger job when Pull request is merged from feature to dev branch. I have use Github Action environment with one protection Rule. Github Action is throwing an error message Branch **"feature" is not allowed to deploy to dev due to environment protection rules.**

Attaching .yaml of workflow.

```
name: "terraform-deploy"
on:
 pull_request:
   types:
     - closed
   branches:
     - dev
jobs:
  dev-plan:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged
    environment:
      name: dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
     - name: "my task"
       run: echo "hello"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using the trigger

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
```

You're running the workflow **on the source branch**  (e.g. `feature/xyz`) once the pull request has been closed (and merged in your case, because you included another condition in the job).

Since you want to run this job on the `dev` branch, I suggest changing your condition to:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [dev]
```

and remove the condition `if: github.event.pull_request.merged`.

With these changes, your workflow is going to be run on any push to `dev`, which includes pull request merges as well as direct pushes.